# How do I select to a div tag without class or id

Tags: html, css, selector

So I have this html code.

```
<div class="someClass">
    <div style="border: red solid 1px;">someText</div>
</div>
```

I want to change the style setting of the  tag that contains "someText".

I've tried `:not([class])` thing, but since this is not the only tag that doesn't have any class or id, it is not applicable. I want to select that particular tag, but have no idea.

Comment: To select an item(s) you need a "hook" that identifies it/them uniquely. You cannot select elements by their contents so you need to find something that identifies **this** element be it `nth-child` or whatever. At the moment this is too vague to answer with any certainty.

Comment: Paulie_D This is technically not true, using Javascript you can select items by their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div {
    /* your styles */
}
```

will work if you want to change the styles of all `div`s.

Otherwise, you can narrow this down, e.g.

```
.someClass div {
    /* your styles */
}
```

would change the style of all `div`s inside an element with the class `someClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... this is a just suggestion that by using [JavaScript HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) selection
to find all div tags that have "someText" **text**

Here is code

```js
var divContent = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
//find all div tag elements

   for(var i = 0; i<divContent.length; i++){
   
       if(divContent.item(i).innerText == "someText"){
       //if you find div tag with "someText" text,
           console.log("found");
           //log "found" on console
   
           divContent.item(i).style.border = "red solid 3px";
           //and style border of 'the' element
           divContent.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
           //background-color: aqua;
       }
   }
```

```css
div{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  border: black solid 1px;
  /*to show how it works*/
}
```

```html
<div>
        
        <div>
            someText
        </div>
        <div>
            someText
        </div>
        <div>
            another text
        </div>
</div>
    
    <div>
        someText
    </div>
    
<div>
  
</div>
```

This is just a suggestion that not using class or ID and detecting contents
that have text line "someText".

I hope you this could help for your curious and hope you have a nice day

Comment: Although html and css alone are difficult, using the DOM concept, which allows javaScript to access html elements, is really easy to change.

Comment: I hope this post would help you to understand what I am saying:
 http://tcpschool.com/javascript/js_dom_concept

Answer (score 0):

In this case this works:

```
.someClass > div {}
```

This selects all div childs of your elements with the class "someClass".

Comment: There may be many divs insisde the parent and we don't know *where* this element is....so this selector is too broad and non-specific.

Comment: That's why I said, in this case it would work. Specifically for the example given.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you do not wish to use an Id or Class, If the tools are there, you might aswell use them or you can use the Nth Child Selector
ie

```
someClass:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: We don't **know** this is the first-child....don't be misled by the OPs simple example code.

Comment: Paulie_D I'm Just going By the Code that he has provided, in which case this would be the correct answer, If it is not & their are other tags then the question should be updated to reflect this.